# Flattr API v2: Get a user

Tags: flattr

shouldn't this get-request return a valid JSON result?

```
https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/users/:der_michael
```

If I open this in my browser I get

```
{"error":"not_found","error_description":"The requested user could not be found","error_uri":"http:\/\/developers.flattr.net\/v2\/#user"}
```

According to the current documentation @ http://developers.flattr.net/v2/#resources this should be a sufficient request, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request is almost correct. There is only a colon ( `:` ) to much.

`https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/users/der_michael`

Good luck!